# How can I have linebreaks in my long LaTeX equations?

Tags: latex

My equation is very long. How do I get it to continue on the next line rather than go off the page?

Comment: I would question if you really want to do that.  Multi-line equations will be very difficult to read.  Is it possible to break up your equation into multiple (shorter) equations?

Comment: Use \notag \\
Check relevant answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74819/aligned-equations-in-latex

Answer (score 169):

If your equation does not fit on a single line, then the `multline` (note that that's **multline** without an "i", not "multiline") environment probably is what you need:

```
\begin{multline}
    first part of the equation \\
    = second part of the equation
\end{multline}
```

If you also need some alignment respect to the first part, you can use `split`:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        first part &= second part #1 \\
        &= second part #2
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Both environments require the `amsmath` package.

See also `aligned` as pointed out [in an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51116894/311834).

Comment: In my experience there can't be a newline inside multline  en equation environments

Comment: `! Package amsmath Error: \begin{multline} allowed only in paragraph mode.`

Comment: @Welgriv are you putting the multline environment inside the equation environment

Answer (score 32):

Not yet mentioned here, another choice is environment `aligned`, again from package [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    A & = B + C\\
      & = D + E + F\\
      & = G
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image: screenshot of output (detail)]

Answer (score 13):

Without configuring your math environment to clip, you could force a new line with two backslashes in a sequence like this:

```
Bla Bla \\ Bla Bla in another line
```

The problem with this is that you will need to determine where a line is likely to end and force to always have a line break there. With equations, rather than text, I prefer this manual way.

You could also use `\\*` to prevent a new page from being started.

Answer (score 10):

If it is inline equation, then use `\allowbreak`. Use it like:

```
$x_1,x_2,x_3,\allowbreak x_4,x_5$.
```

Latex will break equation in this place only if necessary.

Comment: that didn't work for me

Answer (score 7):

I used the `\begin{matrix}`

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
    line_1 \\ 
    line_2 \\ 
    line_3
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple ways you can deal with this. First, and perhaps best, is to rework your equation so that it is not so long; it is likely unreadable if it is that long.

If it must be so, check out the [AMS Short Math Guide](http://ctan.uniminuto.edu/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf) for some ways to handle it. (on the second page)

Personally, I'd use an align environment, so that the breaking and alignment can be precisely controlled. e.g.

```
\begin{align*}
   x&+y+\dots+\dots+x_100000000\\
   &+x_100000001+\dots+\dots
\end{align*}
```

which would line up the first plus signs of each line... but obviously, you can set the alignments wherever you like.

Comment: What is the align* environment good for, with respect to the align environment (with versus without asterisk) ?

Comment: the asterisk tells it to omit numbers for the equation lines.

Answer (score 5):

I think I usually used eqnarray or something. It lets you say

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
    x &=& blah blah blah \\ 
      & & more blah blah blah \\
      & & even more blah blah
\end{eqnarray*}
```

and it will be aligned by the & &... As pkaeding mentioned, it's hard to read, but when you've got an equation thats that long, it's gonna be hard to read no matter what... (The * makes it not have an equation number, IIRC)

Comment: f.y.i. the AMS recommends not using eqnarray environments because they "produce inconsistent spacing of the equal signs and make no attempt to prevent overprinting of the equation body and equation number." -- not really applicable here, but good to know; a good ol' align environment can take care of most such circumstances.

Comment: Is there a way to make this one number the equation also? If I insert a label, I can reference it by number, but it's not printed on the right side of the equation.

Answer (score 4):

`multline` is best to use. Instead, you can use `dmath`, `split` as well.

Here is an example:

```
\begin{multline}
  {\text {\bf \emph {T(u)}}} ={  \alpha *}{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\text{\bf \emph {I(u)}}}{{\text{\bf \emph {S(u,i)}}}* {\text {\bf \emph {Cr(P(u,i))}}} * {\text {\bf \emph {TF(u,i)}}}}}{\text {\bf \emph {I(u)}}}}  \\
   +{  \beta *}{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\text{\bf \emph {$I_h$(u)}}}{{\text{\bf \emph {S(u,i)}}}* {\text {\bf \emph {Cr(P(u,i))}}} * {\text {\bf \emph {TF(u,i)}}}}}{\text {\bf \emph {$I_h$(u)}}}}
\end{multline}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me while using `mathtools` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{multlined}
            first term \\
            second term                 
        \end{multlined}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `eqnarray` and `\nonumber`

example:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    sample = R(s,\pi(s),s') + \gamma V^{\pi} (s') \nonumber \\
    \label{eq:temporal-difference}
     V^{\pi}_{k+1}(s) = (1-\alpha)V^{\pi}(s) - \alpha[sample]
\end{eqnarray}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any extra package to do this:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
     first formula\\
     second formula
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1):

SIMPLE ANSWER HERE

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}

equation \\
here

\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: This is what worked the best for me.  The {split} function was the key.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I used the array environment inside the equation environment like this:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{r c l}
       first Term&=&Second Term\\
                 &=&Third Term
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
```