# New line in equation

Tags: latex, newline

I have such code:

```
\begin{equation*}
        max_X (min_{\vec{Y}} F(X, \vec{Y})) = sup_{X} (inf_{\vec{Y}} F(X, \vec{Y})) = \Gamma_1, \newline
        min_{\vec{Y}} (max_X F(X, \vec{Y})) = inf_{\vec{Y}} (sup_{X} F(X, \vec{Y})) = \Gamma_2        
    \end{equation*}
```

How I set a break line? `\\` doesn't work too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have linebreaks in my long LaTeX equations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860145/how-can-i-have-linebreaks-in-my-long-latex-equations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One first suggestion:

```latex
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{split}
\max_X (\min_{\vec Y} F(X, \vec Y)) = \sup_X (\inf_{\vec Y} F(X, \vec Y)) = \Gamma_1 \\
\min_{\vec Y} (\max_X F(X, \vec Y)) = \inf_{\vec Y} (\sup_X F(X, \vec Y)) = \Gamma_2
\end{split}
\end{displaymath}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max_X (\min_{\vec Y} F(X, \vec Y)) = \sup_X (\inf_{\vec Y} F(X, \vec Y)) = \Gamma_1 \\
\min_{\vec Y} (\max_X F(X, \vec Y)) = \inf_{\vec Y} (\sup_X F(X, \vec Y)) = \Gamma_2
\end{eqnarray*}
```